# can I specific a css class to a kind of tag in a more simple way?

Tags: css

I already have a css class `.table-striped` from bootstrap. And now I want to specific the css class to all `<table>` tag in my page. 
Without adding `.table-striped` to all `<table>` tag `<table class="table-striped">`.
Is there anyway can I do it in a more simple way like this :

```
table {
   .table-striped
}
```

Comment: `table, .table-striped { }`

Comment: Nope you can't do that with pure CSS but you can achieve it with CSS pre-processor. In CSS you can do that table, .table-striped {}.

Comment: I think what OP meant is OP wants to apply props in `.table-striped` to all `table`, without using `class="table-striped"` on `<table>`.

Comment: I try to use pre-processor LESS but fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply the tag for all tables by editing the bootstrap css. Just replace:

```
  .table-striped { ... }
```

with:

```
table { ... }
```

If you can't or don't want to edit the css you can apply the class to all tables with the following script:

```
<script>
  var tables = document.querySelectorAll('table');
  for (var i=0; i<tables.length; i++) tables[i].classList.add('table-striped');
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Adding an script is much simpler. But  if I add a dom element after , I have to call the script again.

Comment: Just put the script at the end of your `<body>` and it will work for all tables.